# Chlorination of propene at 773 K

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-control

The first step of preparation of **glycerol**
with **propene** involves the chlorination of of **propene** at **773 K**. It results to form **allyl chloride**. However the halogenation of alkenes  generally give **vicinal dihalides**

$$\ce{CH3-CH=CH2 + Cl2 -> CH2Cl-CH=CH2}$$

Comment: at that temperature it is a free radical rxn

Comment: Note that the value of 773 K suggest a precision that is not justified. The numerical value is just the result when a temperature of about 500 °C is expressed in kelvin.

Comment: What are you asking for? Are you asking why chlorination of propene leads to formation of allyl chloride and not vicinal dihalide?

Comment: One more thing- low halogen concentration leads to formation of allyl chloride but for high halogen concentration leads to formation of vicinal dihalide. http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/radikale/radi_subst_add_alkane_alkene.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/radikale/radi_brom_allyl/radi_brom_allyl.vscml.html

Comment: @NilayGhosh Do you really think concentration is important in free radical rxn ? it's temp who determines ? Isn't?

Comment: @Nilay: Concentration is important. NBS in CCl4 delivers bromine in low concentration to facilitate a free radical reaction. Free radical halogenation is first order in halogen. Halogenation, at least for bromine, of a double bond is second order in halogen.

Answer (score 2):

The reaction proceeds via a SFR (Substitution Free Radical) mechanism and yields an allylic or benzylic halogenated alkene. This result is specific for low concentration of halogen and high temperature.

The results of the same reaction of halogens with alkenes but at different reaction conditions, i.e. high halogen concentration and room temperature result into anti addition of the halogen atoms on the double bond. Thus the reaction takes place faster in presence of $\ce{CCl4}$, i.e. non polar solvents. The reaction proceeds via formation of cyclic intermediate. The result of the same reaction in water instead of $\ce{CCl4}$ will result in to anti addition of halide ion and $\ce{OH-}$ ion on the double bond.